# Getting wrong result using group by and distinct in hive

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I am creating an aggregated table like

```
create table1 as select 
  country ,
  type_of_order,
  count(distinct order_no) as total_orders
from table2 
   group by country , type_of_order;
```

Now When I am fetching the query

```
select sum(total_orders) from table1 group by country;
```

I am getting different result of total_orders but when I am creating my aggregated table without putting a type_of_order dimension , I am getting different result .
I need to match my data set

I believe groupby is creating groups and my data is getting distinct on the basis of groups.I need to maintain the group by clause

Can anyone help me different way of doing the same in hive

NOTE : - HIVE DOESNT SUPPORT SUBQUERIES

Comment: But it is really 5 distinct values: 1. (One-dot) and 1-4. Also there should be two rows after aggregation because you have two different types, and you are saying that it is single row in the output???

Comment: If you are summarizing count distinct from two rows, then it is wrong. because count distinct is not additive.

Comment: You can not just sum two count distinct. Impossible. Only sketch algorithms like HyperLogLog can sum distinct counts for fast approximation of distinct count on big data.

Comment: You are correct could you suggest me a way of doing it?

Comment: It is not clear what are you doing. Count distinct is not additive - take it as a axiom.  If you want to have accurate resullt along with some aggregation, count distinct in the last aggregation. To help you I need to know details: describe all the scenario, what exact result do you want and query, why are you summarizing distinct counts, maybe it is possible to rewrite.

Comment: if your table1 is kind of reporting table for some BI tools, in which you are going to re-group without some groupby column, then better do not pre-aggregate at all, let it be with order_no. Or prepare different tables each on it's own grain. Or agree with customesr that distinct count is not accurate. Or build query each time and execute it on -demand and calculate each time when group by changed. For accurate count distinct - you do not have other options.  One more way is to count on all possible grains pre-loaded

Comment: Read what Kimball says: https://www.kimballgroup.com/data-warehouse-business-intelligence-resources/kimball-techniques/dimensional-modeling-techniques/additive-semi-additive-non-additive-fact/

Comment: So the actual scenario is , my customer has given me a baseline data and the query he has used to fetch that data, I am implementing the same logic in my hive scripts but , the customer has created separate metrics for good order , bad order  but I am making these as a dimension so I am including an extra group by clause "Type_of_order"  so it's making the count different

Answer (score 0):

First, Hive does support subqueries.

Second, you data has five different values because of the `1.` and `1`.  However, I suspect that the `.` is a function of Stack Overflow.

Probably what is happening is that the values *look* like they are the same.  But if they are strings, they could have hidden characters -- even spaces -- that make them different.

Finding those hidden characters is tricky.  If the first column only has digits, you might want to represent it as a numeric or int.

Comment: I have updated my question , could you have a look over that ?